# Selector for sortable header of ng-table

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using a sortable ng-table to display some data.
Each column has a sorting header. (which is a `<div>` inside a `<th class="sortable">`)

If I try to select the first header using

```
th.sortable > div:nth-child(1)
```

It selects all the divs inside each `<th>`

I forked an existing fiddle and added a block at the top of the css pane.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7mom2ar0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
th.sortable:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

use it like this, if you want first selector for `<th>`
can done like this also. : http://fiddle.jshell.net/bxhcu50a/

```
th.sortable:first-child > div:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```